# What is exact reason behind the execution of finally block in asp.net?i know its by design, in finally block i should do resource cleanup

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

i know its by design, in finally block i should do resource cleanup - that's why the finally block is always executed no matter what the exception handling code is.
But "WHY" it will execute is my question?, this was asked to my friend in an interview, so even i got confused after discussing with him, please clarify, thanks in advance.?

Comment: Please see the information here: http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25614/finally-block-c-sharp

Answer (score 5):

"WHY" here could be summarised as "because that is what the specification says; that is why it was designed, specified, implemented, tested, and supported: because they wanted something that would always execute, no matter what the exception handling code is". It is a bit like asking "WHY does execution flow to the `else` block (if one) if the *condition* in an `if` test fails?"

The *uses* of `finally` include:

- resource cleanup (`Dispose()` being an important one, but not the only one)
- logging / tracing / profiling the fact that we finished (whether successful or not)
- making the state consistent again (for example, resetting an `isRunning` flag)

Anecdotally, I make **much** more use of `finally` than I do `catch`. It is pretty common that I want something to happen while leaving, but often with *exceptions* the best thing to do is to let them bubble upwards. The only thing I usually need to *be sure* to do during an exception is to clean up any mess I made - which I need to do *either way* - so I might as well do that using a combination of `finally` and `using` (which is really just a wrapper around `finally` *anyway*).

Answer (score 4):

It's almost always around resource cleanup - or sometimes *logical* cleanup of getting back to a reasonable state.

If I open a file handle or a database connection (or whatever) then when I leave that piece of code I want the handle to be closed *regardless* of how I leave it - whether it's "normally" or via an exception.

`finally` blocks are simply there to give that "Execute this no matter what<sup>1</sup>" behaviour which can often be useful.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, within reason. Not if the process dies abruptly, for example - of if the power cable is kicked out.